# Performing a correlation on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to do a correlation between multiple columns against one column in pandas? Like:

```
DF[['A']['B']].corr(DF['C'])
```

Comment: Select the required columns say using `loc` and then perform `corr`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) and select multiple columns by `list`:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({

         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'A':[1,3,5,7,1,0],

})

print (DF[['A', 'B']].corrwith(DF['C']))
A    0.319717
B   -0.316862
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In this case I wanted the correlation between C and both A and B not with A and B as individual columns.

Comment: @TatendaDKavu - Can you add some sample with expected output? Be free chnge my sample data.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({

         'Gender':['Male','Female','Male'],
         'Marital_status':['Single','Married','Divorced'],
         'Sport':['Athletics','Soccer',Swimming'],
}) The expected result is as follows: df[['Gender','Marital_status']].corr(df['Sport'])= 0.32 . In other words I want to find out how does gender together with marital status relate to the sports that I like.